# Populate django template with files

Tags: django, django-templates

Django can comfortably populate an HTML template with data from models in a database - but I've recently come across a few scenarios where I would like to populate the template with *other files' data*.
In this case, I'm trying to generate my own documentation for a project. Initially, I just wrote it all into one big file, but this is obviously tedious to handle, and quite repetitive. Instead, I would be neat to have some sort of filesystem, where each folder is a section in the documentation, and each subfolder a subsection, etc etc.

Can Django do this?

I know that one way to do this is to link the files to database objects, then iterate through *these* objects in the template. I'm not keen on this, because I want any changes/new documentation files to immediately show in the page, without having to go edit around in the db.

The only other approach I can think of is to navigate through the folders, adding their contents to page context when a page is loaded. This seems too hacky to me, and will create problems with encoded HTML in the file contents, I imagine.

That being said: if there is an elegant way of doing either of these, or a different approach entirely, I'm all ears.
Cheers

---

By the way, I'm not using any markdown syntax for this - just pure HTML for the documentation pages.

Comment: Have you hear about [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at it briefly. How easy is it to integrate with Django though? Sphinx generates its own files in a folder, and I'm back where I started, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Django has a handy ORM for managing objects in a database, but in the end Django views, forms and templates just handle plain python objects. There's no reason why a django view wouldn't fetch its model from a file. You can create your own model classes that save their data to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

A view does not have to return objects from the database. It can return any Python data structure, regardless of where they came from:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {}
    with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
         lines = []
         for line in f:
            # do some file processing or something
            lines.append(line)
         context['foobar'] = lines
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

The template context will have a list of the lines from `foo.txt` and you'll be able to iterate over it it like it were any other Python object.